# C language, run failed, Decimal to binary

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I'm trying to to convert from a decimal number into a binary number.

Have you any idea why do I have a "run failed" ? (I think that there is a mistake nearby my scanf function).

P.S: I know that the algo of this program is not yet working, but I wanted to try to compile first. But I'm open of any suggestion ^^

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>        

/**
 * Uebung 1.3 - C Teil
 * Programm, welches eine Integer-Zahl in Binärdarstellung ausgibt.
 */

#define DEBUG 1

/** Structure of a binary Value */
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int* valueInBin;
    int valueInDec;
}Wert;

/** Global variables */
//nothing

/** Functions declarations */
void iToBinary(Wert* w);
void printBinaryValue(Wert w);

/** Main function */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Local variable*/
    Wert myVal;

    printf("Wert als Integer (auch negativ): ");
    scanf("%d", &(myVal.valueInDec));
    DEBUG ? printf("Mein Wert : %i", myVal.valueInDec):printf("");
    myVal.size = sizeof(int)*8;
    DEBUG ? printf("size: %i", myVal.size):printf("");

    iToBinary(&myVal);

    printBinaryValue(myVal);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);   
}

void iToBinary(Wert* w){

    int i,temp = w->valueInDec;

    w->size = sizeof(w->valueInDec)*8;

    w->valueInBin = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (int)(w->size)) ;

    for(i=w->size-1; i>=0; i++){
        if(temp > pow(2,i)){
            *((w->valueInBin)+i) = 1;
        }
        else{
            *((w->valueInBin)+i) = 0;
        }
    }
}

void printBinaryValue(Wert w){
    unsigned int i;

    printf("My int in bin : ");
    for(i=0; i<w.size; i++){
        printf("%i",(*(w.valueInBin)+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a "homework" tag to this question.  Also, more detail about the error.  Do you see any other indication of where the problem is other than "Run Failed"?

Comment: There is no compile error, just an "run failed" when I execute the code :Wert als Integer (auch negativ): 2

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 5s)

Comment: What's a "decimal number" or a "binary number"? "Decimal" is a property of the *lexical representation* of a number; the number itself is something more fundamental. "How to print a number as decimal" (or binary) would be a more sensible question.

Comment: Does it fail to compile or link (i.e. when building the program), or when running the program? If it fails when running, try running it in the debugger to see where it stops, or to step though the program line by line while checking the variables.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You're correct on this, but painfully pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
for(i=w->size-1; i>=0; i++)
```

You're actually running an infinite loop. Change `i++` to `i--`.

Your code also contains some errors in functions `iToBinary` and `printBinaryValue`. Try to catch the bugs!

BTW, a recursive function can do it in a much better way! If you don't have any restrictions, do give it a thought.

Comment: Mmmh I've to admit I don't see my errors in iToBinary and printBinaryValue :s

Comment: Ohh you are right, a recursive function can be much better ! (I didn't even think about it!)

Comment: Correctly no, I mean the algo is not correct but I've no errors

Comment: My iToBin function :
    for(i=w->size-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(temp > pow(2,i)){
            *((w->valueInBin)+i) = 1;
            temp -= pow(2,i);
        }
        else{
            *((w->valueInBin)+i) = 0;
        }
    }

Comment: I've found my error (--i and not i-- ...), here my working code :